# Proper Way to Validate Client-Certificates - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, iis

I am attempting to build an application that would make use of client-certificates to authenticate the user attempting to access the application. I am using a self-signed CA as described [here](http://manmoahn-openssl-net.blogspot.com/2011/07/creating-serverclient-certificate-pair.html).  While, I have done quite a bit of research, I have yet to come away with the "proper" approach to authenticating a client-certificate.

1. First, it seems as if this can be done at both the application level (using .NET classes such as X509 store) or in IIS itself. What are the advantages or disadvantages of each approach?
2. If I were to choose to validate the certificate with in my application code, what is the proper field to validate? For example, [this question uses the serial number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489745/how-to-send-client-certificate-using-httpwebrequest-and-iisexpress-for-debugging). However, for my "test" certificates, the serial number is literally four characters (not counting spaces). What is the proper approach to ensuring that the client-certificate really was issued by me?
3. I attempted to apply this at the server level (I am using IIS Express for testing). However, I do not get a request for a certificate, just a 403.7 - Forbidden, error ( with the following web.config settings `<access sslFlags="Ssl,SslNegotiateCert,SslRequireCert" /`>). However, if I remove SslRequireCert, I am able to at least "see" many certificates using the following code snippet:

   ```
       X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
       store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
       X509Certificate cert = store.Certificates[0];
   ```

Even if this issue (3) were resolved, is there any way, using IIS, to authenticate a certificate without having to map it to [a Windows account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/iisclientcertificatemappingauthentication/)?

I have tried installing the client certificate both in Firefox and in my PCs keystore. Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?  Which is able to see the those certificates from the X509Store, your web app or your client program?